# Svelte3 Sapper: How to make parent layout update on store update? Can I transfer data between nested layouts module scripts?

Tags: svelte, sapper

I'm 3 days in Svelte3 and Sapper and they are so cool, but I'm not sure I'm cooking them correctly.

My app simplified structure:

```
├── routes
│   ├── _error.svelte
│   ├── _layout.svelte // parent layout (PL)
│   ├── index.svelte
│   ├── catalog
│   │   ├── _layout.svelte // child layout (CL)
│   │   ├── [cat].svelte // first level category (1L)
│   │   ├── [cat]
│   │   │   ├── [subcat].svelte // second level category (2L)
```

What's happening:

1) My PL contains header menu so I ask categories data from it's module script using preload(page, session) and this.fetch. Also I have to do some logic there, so I get path data (slugs). I .set categories and path data in store in PL simple script.

2) CL contains Breadcrumbs component. Breadcrumbs takes $pathData from store (I need this data to be in store for other logic). SSR shows logic works as expected.

3) As I need to change Breadcrumbs while I move between catalog pages I should also change path data in store so each route .svelte has module script with Preload returning params. In simple script I .update(old => new) path data in store.

I expected Breadcrumbs to update automatically once I've changed store but it updates only if I change route i.e navigate from L1 to L2 or back (). While I'm navigating between categories of one level breadcrumbs do not change.

Questions:

1) Is it correct behavior or I've broke something? If correct how should I update breadcrumbs? I can put them in L1 and L2 but it seems logically strange because of repeating code.

1.1) I'll read more about regular expressions in routes - it seems to be way to replace L1 and L2 .svelte with one file - it solves problem of repeating code. But ideally breadcrumbs should be placed in PL so I can face the same update problem again. I've seen https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_element_property and sections bellow but I can't understand is it my case and what and where should I write.

2) Is there any way to pass variables from PL module script to CL module script? I need to do or not products request from CL depending on categories data I get in PL but store is not available in module script so now I do products request if necessary in PL (can't do products request in simple script because need SSR of products). It seems strange because products request obviously belongs to catalog layout (CL) or routes - not PL! API I work with is strange - I know but there must be a way...

Update:

3) I've red docs about regex in routes and I didn't find answer how to present all my catalog routes as one route. Can I describe catalog/[cat] and catalog/[cat]/[subcat] routes as one route?

I'm almost sure there is a mistake, but I can't find it.
https://bitbucket.org/LittleToky/rerooms-store-svelte/commits/50dde002fe9c8ae91a3276bd9a551a7b26841d3c
If someone will test it:
First navigate to
/rooms/living/miebiel/miaghkaia-miebiel/
and click different categories in side menu.
[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5RVv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create a single store (separate file) for the breadcrumbs and use this in both layouts components.
Using stores is the recommended method to share state between components.